# Array of Struct pointers, getting segfault

Tags: c++, pointers

I get segfault for the following:

myclass.h

```
class myclass
{
    struct stuSomething
    {
        ...
        stuSomething(){...}
    };

public:
    static myclass* Instance()
    {
        if (!instance)
            new myclass();
        return instance;
    }
    void myclass:someFun();

private:
    static myclass *instance;
    myclass();
    stuSomething *stuStack[SAMPLE_QUANTITY];
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
myclass* myclass::instance;
myclass::myclass()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_QUANTITY; i++)
        this->stuStack[i] = NULL;
    instance = this;
}

myclass::someFun()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_QUANTITY; i++)
        if(this->stuStack[i] != NULL) // I get segfault here! for i = 0
            ...
}
```

But wierd enuogh, when I put

```
for(int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_QUANTITY; i++)
    if(this->stuStack[i] != NULL) 
        ...
```

in the constructor right after I fill in the stuStack I dont get segfault.

I feel like there is something obvious I'm missing. What causes the problem?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows us how you *use* the class and the functions.

Comment: Is `this` pointer valid?

Comment: Is stustack member variablw

Comment: @gomons When I was trying to re-write my code in the question I realised I had forgot to add `instance = this;` in my constructor! I think that's why `this` was not a valid pointer. Post as an Answer so I could accept!

Comment: Generally speaking, don't set static member variables in constructors. Instead in the `Instance` static member function do e.g. `instance = new myclass;`.

Comment: That's why it's also important to get the main so we know how you call the function and what else you have been doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `this` pointer, it can be invalid.